# Testing user account alfresco CMIS if exist

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, alfresco, cmis

I am working in a `JavaEE` project and i want simply see if the user ho logged in with a `username` and a `password` have an account in `Alfresco`, I user the `getSession` method but it doesn't return if the `username` and `password` are wrong (doesn't exist).

```
private static Session getSession(String serverUrl, String username, String password) {
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = SessionFactoryImpl.newInstance();
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put(SessionParameter.USER, username);
    params.put(SessionParameter.PASSWORD, password);
    params.put(SessionParameter.ATOMPUB_URL, serverUrl);
    params.put(SessionParameter.BINDING_TYPE, BindingType.ATOMPUB.value());
    List<Repository> repos = sessionFactory.getRepositories(params);
    if (repos.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println(" repository doesn't exist ");
        throw new RuntimeException("Server has no repositories!");
    }
    return repos.get(0).createSession();
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many research i discover the `Rest Api` for `Alfresco`

```
GET /alfresco/service/api/people/{userName}
```

for my case I used it and worked for me

you can find more in this link https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Repository_RESTful_API_Reference (how to add a person, how to check if someone is a member of a private site ... ).