# Get if a user is in a specific alfresco site

Tags: jakarta-ee, alfresco, alfresco-share, cmis

I am working in a `JavaEE` project and i want simply see if a user is a member of an private `Alfresco` site using CMIS. I need to see if the user is a member of this (private,public) Site and his current situation in this site.

Comment: Then i deleted my comment, sorry.

Comment: Not sure you can do it easily from CMIS. Are you happy to call out to the normal Alfresco REST APIs?

Comment: @Gagravarr after many search i think that i will use REST API to make it happen is it ok to post the answer or i have to edit my post and change the tag (mean that remove CMIS tag for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot easily do this with CMIS alone. But you can use the SiteService because it has an [isMember method](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/org/alfresco/service/cmr/site/SiteService.html#isMember-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-). This would only work if your code is running in the same process as Alfresco (like in an action, behavior, or web script).

If you are running code in a separate process from Alfresco, consider writing a web script that would leverage the same method, then call your web script from your code using a rest client.

Alternatively, you could use the [Site Members public REST API](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/pra/1/concepts/pra-sites-members.html).

Resist the urge to use other "slingshot" REST URLs you might find unless they are explicitly marked as "public".

Comment: you can see more in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38694684/testing-user-account-alfresco-cmis-if-exist