# OpenCmis client - create alfresco tags

Tags: python, alfresco, opencmis

I'm trying to create a script to upload docs into an Alfresco repository using the opencmis library (python). Uploading the actual document is fine, but I'm bending my brain on how to add tags to the document.

I was thinking along the lines of:

```
props = doc.getProperties()
tagname = ['test']
tag = {"cm:taggable": tagname}
doc.updateProperties(tag)
```

But this throws a http 500 error

Any idea's anyone?

Answer (score 2):

I am fairly certain that tags cannot be manipulated via CMIS. Instead, use the [Alfresco REST API](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/references/RESTful-TaggingNodeTagsPost.html). It has support for tagging.

Comment: IC, seems like I need to mix and match REST and CIMS, found this page which is useful to see what function is supported where. http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/references/dev-api-func-tags.html

Comment: Jeff Potts is a 100% true, CMIS is limited for example you can't see if a person is a memeber of a site look to my post [Get if a user is in a specific alfresco site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38720618/get-if-a-user-is-in-a-specific-alfresco-site)

Comment: Well, with CMIS 1.1 , you can add the "cm:taggable" aspect using Python cmislib (by Jeff Potts!), as aspects are considered as secondary properties. 
Use the "cmis:secondaryObjectTypeIds" property.
After that, I could not find a way to add tags afterwards, except through REST API which is kindof wourkaround.