# CmisObjectNotFoundException when trying to access my Alfresco repository

Tags: java, web-services, alfresco, opencmis

I'm new with CMIS and Alfresco and I got this error when in try to connect to my Alfresco's repository using AtomPUB binding. I have no idea about the source of my problem. Is it unless a functionality ? Is it my Credential ? 
When I install it, I choose only :
- Alfresco community
- Solr4

How should I do if I want to use web services ? Should I install a specific plugin in my Alfresco ?

I got with error :

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/ME%2ME/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-simple/1.7.9/slf4j-simple-1.7.9.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/ME%2ME/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.3/logback-classic-1.1.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLoggerFactory]
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.exceptions.CmisObjectNotFoundException: Introuvable
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.AbstractAtomPubService.convertStatusCode(AbstractAtomPubService.java:499)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.AbstractAtomPubService.read(AbstractAtomPubService.java:701)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.AbstractAtomPubService.getRepositoriesInternal(AbstractAtomPubService.java:873)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.RepositoryServiceImpl.getRepositoryInfos(RepositoryServiceImpl.java:66)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.impl.RepositoryServiceImpl.getRepositoryInfos(RepositoryServiceImpl.java:92)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.SessionFactoryImpl.getRepositories(SessionFactoryImpl.java:120)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.SessionFactoryImpl.getRepositories(SessionFactoryImpl.java:107)
    at fr.omb.TestOMB.connect(TestOMB.java:160)
    at fr.omb.TestOMB.main(TestOMB.java:35)
```

My code :

```
package fr.omb;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.api.CmisObject;
import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.api.Document;
import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.api.Folder;
import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.api.Repository;
import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.api.Session;
import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.api.SessionFactory;
import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.SessionFactoryImpl;
import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.PropertyIds;
import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.SessionParameter;
import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.data.ContentStream;
import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.enums.BaseTypeId;
import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.enums.BindingType;
import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.enums.UnfileObject;
import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.enums.VersioningState;
import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.exceptions.CmisObjectNotFoundException;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

public class TestOMB {

    private static Session session;
    private static final String ALFRSCO_ATOMPUB_URL = "http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/cmis";
    private static final String TEST_FOLDER_NAME = "chemistryTestFolder";
    private static final String TEST_DOCUMENT_NAME_1 = "chemistryTest1.txt";
    private static final String TEST_DOCUMENT_NAME_2 = "chemistryTest2.txt";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Folder root = connect();
        cleanup(root, TEST_FOLDER_NAME);
        Folder newFolder = createFolder(root, TEST_FOLDER_NAME);
        createDocument(newFolder, TEST_DOCUMENT_NAME_1);
        createDocument(newFolder, TEST_DOCUMENT_NAME_2);
        System.out.println("+++ List Folder +++");
        listFolder(0, newFolder);
        DeleteDocument(newFolder, "/" + TEST_DOCUMENT_NAME_2);
        System.out.println("+++ List Folder +++");
        listFolder(0, newFolder);
    }

    /**
     * Clean up test folder before executing test
     * 
     * @param target
     * @param delFolderName
     */
    private static void cleanup(Folder target, String delFolderName) {
        try {
            CmisObject object = session.getObjectByPath(target.getPath() + delFolderName);
            Folder delFolder = (Folder) object;
            delFolder.deleteTree(true, UnfileObject.DELETE, true);
        } catch (CmisObjectNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("No need to clean up.");
        }
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param target
     */
    private static void listFolder(int depth, Folder target) {
        String indent = StringUtils.repeat("\t", depth);
        for (Iterator<CmisObject> it = target.getChildren().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            CmisObject o = it.next();
            if (BaseTypeId.CMIS_DOCUMENT.equals(o.getBaseTypeId())) {
                System.out.println(indent + "[Docment] " + o.getName());
            } else if (BaseTypeId.CMIS_FOLDER.equals(o.getBaseTypeId())) {
                System.out.println(indent + "[Folder] " + o.getName());
                listFolder(++depth, (Folder) o);
            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * Delete test document
     * 
     * @param target
     * @param delDocName
     */
    private static void DeleteDocument(Folder target, String delDocName) {
        try {
            CmisObject object = session.getObjectByPath(target.getPath() + delDocName);
            Document delDoc = (Document) object;
            delDoc.delete(true);
        } catch (CmisObjectNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("Document is not found: " + delDocName);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create test document with content
     * 
     * @param target
     * @param newDocName
     */
    private static void createDocument(Folder target, String newDocName) {
        Map<String, String> props = new HashMap<String, String>();
        props.put(PropertyIds.OBJECT_TYPE_ID, "cmis:document");
        props.put(PropertyIds.NAME, newDocName);
        System.out.println("This is a test document: " + newDocName);
        String content = "aegif Mind Share Leader Generating New Paradigms by aegif corporation.";
        byte[] buf = null;
        try {
            buf = content.getBytes("UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ByteArrayInputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(buf);
        ContentStream contentStream = session.getObjectFactory().createContentStream(newDocName, buf.length,
                "text/plain; charset=UTF-8", input);
        target.createDocument(props, contentStream, VersioningState.MAJOR);
    }

    /**
     * Create test folder directly under target folder
     * 
     * @param target
     * @param createFolderName
     * @return newly created folder
     */
    private static Folder createFolder(Folder target, String newFolderName) {
        Map<String, String> props = new HashMap<String, String>();
        props.put(PropertyIds.OBJECT_TYPE_ID, "cmis:folder");
        props.put(PropertyIds.NAME, newFolderName);
        Folder newFolder = target.createFolder(props);
        return newFolder;
    }

    /**
     * Connect to alfresco repository
     * 
     * @return root folder object
     */
    private static Folder connect() {
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = SessionFactoryImpl.newInstance();
        Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();

        // User credentials.
        parameters.put(SessionParameter.USER, "myuser");
        parameters.put(SessionParameter.PASSWORD, "mypassword");

        // Connection settings.
        parameters.put(SessionParameter.BINDING_TYPE, BindingType.ATOMPUB.value());
        parameters.put(SessionParameter.ATOMPUB_URL, ALFRSCO_ATOMPUB_URL);
        parameters.put(SessionParameter.AUTH_HTTP_BASIC, "true");
        parameters.put(SessionParameter.COOKIES, "true");

        parameters.put(SessionParameter.OBJECT_FACTORY_CLASS,
                "org.alfresco.cmis.client.impl.AlfrescoObjectFactoryImpl");

        // Create session.
        // Alfresco only provides one repository.
        Repository repository = sessionFactory.getRepositories(parameters).get(0);
        Session session = repository.createSession();
        return session.getRootFolder();
    }

}
```

Comment: Try to change your Alfresco Atom pub to `http://127.0.0.1:8080/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.0/atom` and tell me if it change something

Comment: Hello, I tried to change http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/cmis by http://127.0.0.1:8080/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/ver‌​sions/1.0/atom but it does not work. I have the same error.

Comment: I think that you are not getting the session with the right way please read this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38694684/testing-user-account-alfresco-cmis-if-exist

Comment: just in case please change 8080 to 8084

Comment: I know the error is linked with the path of TEST_FOLDER_NAME  please start with "/" it's mean the root and go to your folder

Comment: With 8084 I get the same exception but a different error message : Cannot access "http://localhost:8084/alfresco/service/cmis": Connection refused: connect

Comment: when I try this URL http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/cmis in Chrome i get a 404 error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, it's because of Alfresco's version. Since the V4.x the url of the AtomPUB is http://localhost:8080/alfresco/cmisatom.

https://community.alfresco.com/docs/DOC-5527-cmis

- For Alfresco 3.x : http://[host]:[port]/alfresco/service/cmis
- For Alfresco 4.0.x, Alfresco 4.1.x and Alfresco 4.2.a-c: http://[host]:[port]/alfresco/cmisatom
- For Alfresco 4.2.d-f, Alfresco 5.0 and Alfresco 5.1: http://[host]:[port]/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.0/atom

Comment: To anyone else coming across this exception it basically means your provided endpoint is not accessible. It would have been nice if they threw a more descriptive exception, but it is what it is.