# "Unkown repository" error when trying to getFolderRoot from Alfresco 5.0 repository with CMIS

Tags: java, alfresco, cmis

I have a new alfresco community version 5.0.a installation.  I'm trying to use a java connector service to upload/download files that works correctly with a 4.2.c alfresco installation.

This connector application uses chemistry-opencmis-client-api-0.8.0.

When uploading a file using the connector, I open the connection, get the repository and also can get the repository root folder id correctly:

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = SessionFactoryImpl.newInstance();
Map<String, String> parameter = new HashMap<String, String>();

parameter.put(SessionParameter.BINDING_TYPE, BindingType.ATOMPUB.value());
parameter.put(SessionParameter.ATOMPUB_URL , url );
parameter.put(SessionParameter.USER        , user);
parameter.put(SessionParameter.PASSWORD    , pass);

if (repository_id != null)
    parameter.put(SessionParameter.REPOSITORY_ID, repository_id);

List<Repository> repos = sessionFactory.getRepositories(parameter);     
Repository repo = repos.get(0);
log.debug("REPO ID: " + repo.getId());
log.debug("REPO ROOT FOLDER ID: " + repo.getRootFolderId());
```

Then I create the session:

```
Session session = repo.createSession();
```

But when I want to get the root folder object:

```
Folder folder = session.getRootFolder();
```

I get a "CmisObjectNotFoundException: Unknown repository" error:

> org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.exceptions.CmisObjectNotFoundException:
>   Unknown repository!   at
>   org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.AbstractAtomPubService.getObjectInternal(AbstractAtomPubService.java:768)
>     at
>   org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.ObjectServiceImpl.getObject(ObjectServiceImpl.java:516)
>     at
>   org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.SessionImpl.getObject(SessionImpl.java:403)
>     at
>   org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.SessionImpl.getObject(SessionImpl.java:377)
>     at
>   org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.SessionImpl.getRootFolder(SessionImpl.java:482)
>     at
>   org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.SessionImpl.getRootFolder(SessionImpl.java:476)
>     at com.test.ecm.EcmConnector.open(EcmConnector.java:62)
>     at
>   com.test.ecm.WebServiceController.post(WebServiceController.java:99)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:751)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)  at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:341)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:238)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3363)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3333)
>     at
>   weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
>     at
>   weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2220)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2146)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2124)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1564)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:254)
>     at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:295)  at
>   weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:254)

What could be the cause for this error?

Comment: The class `com.test.ecm.EcmConnector` looks very suspicious - what other jars did you add? Any demo ones? Any custom cmis ones?

Comment: See if this link helps you :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41580963/cmisobjectnotfoundexception-when-trying-to-access-my-alfresco-repository

Comment: @Gagravarr WebServiceController and EcmConnector are my project classes.  No additional cmis jars.

Comment: @SanketMehta Thanks, I'm using the correct url for alfresco 5: http://localhost:8080/alfresco/cmisatom.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the incorrect service URL. According to the [documentation](https://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/pra/1/concepts/cmis-request-url-format-onpremise.html), the URL for CMIS 1.0 and the ATOM binding is:

https://localhost:8080/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.0/atom